# $A,B$ are torsion-free abelian groups such that $A\otimes \Bbb{Q}\cong B\otimes\Bbb{Q}$ as $\Bbb{Q}$ module then $A\cong B$ as abelian groups (T/F)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups

I can show that $A\otimes \Bbb{Q}\cong S^{-1}A$ as $\Bbb{Q}$ where $S=\Bbb{Z}^*$.

I can see the statement is false when $A$ or $B$ is not torsion free, for instance $A=\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $B=\Bbb{Z}_3$, here both $A\otimes \Bbb{Q}$, $B\otimes \Bbb{Q}$ are zero.

Can anyone give me any idea or way out for the problem?

Comment: Start by proving that this is true when $A$ and $B$ are free. How would you try to extend this proof to the case when $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily free? Will you hit any snags?

Comment: This is false without any further assumptions on $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every commutative ring $R$ and every multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$ we have the isomorphism of $S^{-1} R$-algebras
$$
  (S^{-1} R) ⊗_R (S^{-1} R)
  ≅
  S^{-1} R \,,
  \quad
  x ⊗ y \mapsto x y \,.
$$
This entails that
$$
  ℚ ⊗_ℤ ℚ ≅ ℚ
$$
as $ℚ$-vector spaces.
But we also have
$$
  ℚ ⊗_ℤ ℤ ≅ ℚ
$$
as $ℚ$-vector spaces.
The abelian groups $ℚ$ and $ℤ$ are non-isomorphic (because $ℚ$ is divisible but $ℤ$ is not), so the statement is false.